How to manage child’s iPhone from parent’s Macbook
I have set up my child's iPhone using my icloud.com apple-id.
So we now have:

Child apple id: child@icloud.com
Parent apple id: parent@icloud.com

During the setup I received a code on my MacBook that I had to type in the iPhone.
After setup completed I cannot see my child's account in my MacBook's parental controls. So now how can I set time limits, allow apps and so on?
One possible reason could be that the apple-id associated with my MacBook was a different one from the apple-id I used to set up the iPhone. The apple-id I used to set up the iPhone was set up as one of the internet accounts on my MacBook. So the MacBook know about two ids:

MacBook apple-id used for appstore: othermail@example.com
Parent's other apple-id: parent@icloud.com

I have tried to fix this by removing the account that was associated with the previous apple-id and removing and then adding the icloud.com address I used to install the child's iPhone.
This did not fix the problem.
All I want is to be able to manage my child's iPhone, how can I do this from a MacBook? Is that even possible or can the iPhone only be managed from the iPhone itself using the 4 digit screen code I had to set up?
Also, is the parent side parental control tied to my apple-id or to my device? And in case of the former, does that mean I can access them (ie manage my child's iPhone) from any device I login and add my iCloud account (parent@icloud.com) to?

Does your child have an Apple account that is different log in than your Apple account? Do t tell us the log in names of all accounts, but specify them a@whatever.com b@icloid.com and c@foo.com for every distinct account and label which is you and which is the child, please with an edit to the post

It’s not clear what your setup is, but it sounds messy without knowing precisely which account is in one of several spots on several devices.
I would try to not share an account with anyone. One account for one parent and a different account for each child or other person in the family group.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/102617


Instead of sharing an account with your child, which can give them unwanted access to your personal data, create an Apple Account for them.

Hopefully the above path is one that makes sense for your needs.

Thanks @bmike, i have added a clarification to my question.

Ok. Let me think through those complications. My general advice is you make your iCloud the parent and put all the old purchasing accounts under the family to share the past purchases and move forward with one and only one account for each person.

The fix for me was to make a new, additional account for myself on the macbook and use this new account to log into the Apple-id of the parent account.
After this I can use parental controls when I logout of my account and log in with the new account.

There seems to be a final, uncheagable and mostly undocumented bond between macbook account and Apple-id.
Searching for 'change Apple-id' leads to instructions on how to change the email address that is used for the Apple-id.
I tried but was not able to change my apple-id mail address into the mail address used for the parent Apple-id. Apparently one cannot rewire the account on a macbook to a different Apple-id.
Why my macbook received the login-codes to the parent Apple-id while logged in with the alternate Apple-id, I do not know. I will ask a separate question about this.
Finally, parental controls are only available through 'Family sharing' from OSX v10.10 onwards. If you do not see parental controls after setting up your child's account, check your macbook OSX version.
